# Table aligned with Section of Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to display a table in line with a section of a form.

Here is what I am looking for:

```
#Form

Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Label:  |TextBox|                  |-----------  Table  -----------|
Label:  |TextBox|                  |-------------------------------|
Label:  |TextBox|                  |-------------------------------|
Label:  |TextBox|                  |-------------------------------|
Label:  |TextBox|                  |-------------------------------|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|
Label:  |TextBox|

#End of Form
```

I have created a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FIysK8qtFp) to assist in what my source is looking like and so you can manipulate it as much as you want.

Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<form>    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr>


    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field OfficerID must be a number." data-val-required="The OfficerID field is required." id="OfficerID" name="OfficerID" type="hidden" value="2">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DateEntered">Date Entered:</label>
        <div style="width:26.5%" class="col-md-10">
            <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-group date">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date Entered: must be a date." data-val-required="The Date Entered: field is required." id="DateEntered" name="DateEntered" type="datetime" value="09/19/2016">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DateEntered" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="WOption">Test</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="radio">
                <input id="WTCheck" name="WOption" type="radio" value="Test 1">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="WOption" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="WOption">Test 2</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="radio">
                <input id="BCheck" name="WOption" type="radio" value="Test 2">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="WOption" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="AWOption" class="form-group">
        <hr>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AWeight">AW:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AW: must be a number." id="AW" name="AW" type="number" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AW" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="BFTSelect" class="form-group">
        <hr>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="TestTypeID">Test Type:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="TestTypeID" name="TestTypeID">    <option value="">-- Select Test --</option>
                <option value="1">S Assessment</option>
                <option value="2">US Assessment</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TestTypeID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>






    <div id="S-Area">
        <hr>

        <div id="S-Measure">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SCT">C/T:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field C/T: must be a number." id="SCT" name="SCT" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SCT" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SAS">A/S:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field A/S: must be a number." id="SAS" name="SAS" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SAS" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ST">T:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field T: must be a number." id="ST" name="ST" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ST" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="STotal">Total:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Total: must be a number." id="STotal" name="STotal" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="STotal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="SPercentile">Percentile:</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Percentile: must be a number." id="SPercentile" name="SPercentile" type="number" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SPercentile" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>


            <div id="S-Limits-M" class="right-table">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>20 - 29</td>
                        <td>18.60%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>30-39</td>
                        <td>21.30%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>40-49</td>
                        <td>23.40%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>50-59</td>
                        <td>24.60%</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>





    </div>
```

Comment: Embed the elements in second `row` in two separate column's `.col-md-`

Comment: @LJ can you be more specific in regards to `second row`?

Comment: Second `row` is the one which holds two groups (Label-Textbox group and Table group); Why don't use bootstrap grid logic inside that to make it a `row` with two columns `col-md-`,  one for Label-Textbox group and second for Table group?

Comment: @LJ if I am following correctly, I have tried [this](http://www.bootply.com/OX8lmaqVTr) and it shrunk the label-textbox and still didn't put the table next to that section of the form

Comment: Check this fork - http://www.bootply.com/oagXaVolfZ#

Comment: @LJ you sure you forked it? The table isn't inline with the section of the form

Comment: My bad - http://www.bootply.com/oagXaVolfZ#

Comment: @LJ your idea helped me get it working! if you want to post your idea I will mark it as accepted. I also asked the same question but none of those answers helped either so if you want to post your answer on both of my questions I will mark them both as accepted.

Comment: I would suggest you post an answer on how you tackled the case with some explanation so that the community would better benefit. Cheers!

Comment: @LJ just posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the help of L J.

Inside the `form` I included another `row` and separated the section of the form and the table that I wanted to display next to each other in their own `div`'s.

After the separation I gave them their own `col-md-` value which worked perfectly.

As a visual for what I did:

```
<form>

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Test</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Test</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <caption class="text-center">Limits</caption>
              <tr>
                <td>20 - 29</td>
                <td>22.70%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>30-39</td>
                <td>24.60%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>40-49</td>
                <td>27.60%</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>50-59</td>
                <td>30.40%</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Here is the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/3qucO9wtDL)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be utilizing Bootstrap's native grid, but otherwise this is really just simple markup. If each 'section' of fields has a container of some sort (div, fieldset, etc.) Just float your table:

```css
input {
  display:block;
  }
table {
  float: right;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <input type="text" name="group1_field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="group1_field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="group1_field3"/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>table row 1<td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>table row 2<td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>table row 3<td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <input type="text" name="group2_field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="group2_field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="group2_field3"/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 3</legend>
    <input type="text" name="group3_field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="group3_field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="group3_field3"/>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Anyway you could do this with the code I supplied in the Bootply?